# Error Adding a Switch Mediator inside a Proxy Service in WSO2 Developer Studio

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm trying to do a simple Proxy Service using the Developer Studio tool from the open-source SOA middleware provider WSO2.

When I drag into the flow a Switch Mediator in the graphical view there is no problem but when I changed to the text view, I'm facing the following error:

```
Cannot update source view. The following error(s) have been detected 
Reason: XPathFactoty#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactoty for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactotyConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactotyConfigurationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoty: bundleresource://1013.fwk317983781:21/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFa ctory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
```

And the XML is empty, so I can't to add any Switch Mediator and get it working with the WSO2 DS.

This is happening with the 3.5.0 and 3.6.0 version of the tool, and I even try one of the sample in the website but with the same result.

Anyone have any reason why this error is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the java version that your using?

Comment: Java 1.7.0. (The same issue is in the WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.0 RC2)

Answer (score 0):

Each switch element needs to have an attribute called 'source'.  This is the Xpath attribute that is checked against the criteria in each case.  To add the 'source' attribute, type the Xpath and then click 'update' or 'save'.  With that required attribute, a valid xml configuration file may be created and viewed as text.

Here is more documentation on the switch mediator: https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Switch+Mediator

Comment: I just want to share a youtube video when you can see the error I was talking about. As you can see it's not related with the source field or something like that. [video](http://youtu.be/WoRf4Sv18WY)